# VIrtualbox Windows 7 Guest OS not recognizing USB Devices

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Windows 7 as a VM in Virtualbox.  I have created the group vboxusers and have set my main account as part of the group.

Whenever I enter the Win7 machine it can not detected my USB flash drive.  I go in Device Manager and try to find the driver online but it doesn't find it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install Guest Additions on the guest?

Comment: Is VirtualBox set to allow the guest to access USB devices?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that your pendrive's version is 2.0 or 3.0.So that you have to install an extension in virtual box.Refer the link below to download the extension which is supported for all platforms....https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.8/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.8.vbox-extpack for installation tips refer this link https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing